# Running java program, maven project on intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I feel as though I am missing a very simple step or misunderstood something. I cant seem to run (on intellij) my java program that I wrote in my maven project.

I wrote some code and added some dependencies. The code has no errors. I want to test this code but I cannot because the "play" button to run the program is grayed out. Also when I right click my file to try and find run program, it does not appear!

I think the problem might be because my code states that my `main()` is never used. Not really sure why it isnt being used. I thought the compiler always looks for a main() to compile/run

```
public static void main() {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Not sure how I can test this program. Can someone help me with my problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Edit your main method to this signature and try again.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: In addition to this, you can have IntelliJ generate the `main` method by using `psvm` **Tab**.